# prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol + NSManagedObject Subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

So I get the compile error "prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol" in an xcode generated NS Managed Object subclass. The error is matched to the line `@class AnswerSet, Section, SurveyStyle;` and then all lines where these objects are used. The error seemed to have come at random but I am fairly convinced it originated from deleting some of the generated classes and then re-building them.

The code in the class is irrelevant as it worked before and compiles when I copy it into a new project.

So far I have tried deleting them all again and rebuilding. Cleaning the project. Restarting ect.

My last resort will be to copy everything across into a new project file and/or refactor what I have but I'm hoping someone can suggest something to save me from that!

Edit: Just attempted to rename the entity/class of the offending file. Xcode hanged and I force quit it. Renamed the file and refactored. Ended up with the same issue.

Comment: can you show the lines for '@interface' and '@implement' in your .h and .m files, respectively?

Comment: Its x-code standard generated code which when copied across to another project compiles without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the error was a result of a stray character outside the comments at the top of a class. Not sure why it didnt pick it up but it took a long time to track it down!

Answer (score 0):

Add The piece of code in implementation file(.m)import
AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h